# Show that $\{ x \in X: \langle w, x\rangle = b \}$ has dimension one less than $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Consider the *hyperplane*
$$
H := \left\{\mathrm x \in X: \langle \mathrm{w, x}\rangle = b \right\},
$$
and suppose that $\mathrm{e_1} \dots, \mathrm{e_n}$ is a basis for $X$. $H$ isn't necessarily a subspace of $X$ - it need not contain the zero vector - but if one looks up a "Hyperplane" on Wikipedia it is stated that a hyperplane is an affine subspace of $X$.  Is it possible to explicitly derive a basis of $n-1$ vectors for this affine subspace $H$; thereby showing that the dimension of $H$ is at most $n-1$?

Thanks!

Comment: As you correctly mention, the affine subspace need not be a vector space at all. To answer your question, do you know that given any affine subspace $S \subseteq X$, $\exists x \in X$, and $W \leq X$ such that $S = x + W$? ($A \leq B$ means $A$ is a subspace of $B$)

Comment: The hyperplane we're interested in is $w^Tx = b$. What if you write $b = w^Tx_0$ for some $x_0 \in X$ and $w^T(x-x_0) = 0$? Does this help? Lastly, note that $\{ x \in X: w^Tx = 0\} \leq X$